# realm.xamarin thows error "Data type mismatch" even when same data type

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

i am using realm.xamarin 0.75 with xamarin forms and while executing query, i get a weird error. the query is

```
DateTimeOffset fromOffset = new DateTimeOffset(fromDate);
DateTimeOffset toOffset = new DateTimeOffset(toDate);
var config = DependencyService.Get<IDatabase>().GetConfiguration();
using (var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config))
{
    return realm.All<Measurements>()Where(o => o.CreatedDateTime >= fromOffset && o.CreatedDateTime <= toOffset).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDateTime).ToList();
}
```

And the error is:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505): Realms.RealmException: Data type mismatch
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.NativeCommon.ExceptionThrower (NativeException exception) [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) Realms.NativeCommon:ExceptionThrower (Realms.NativeException)
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Realms.NativeQuery:timestamp_milliseconds_greater_equal (Realms.QueryHandle,intptr,long)
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.AddQueryGreaterThanOrEqual (Realms.QueryHandle queryHandle, System.String columnName, System.Object value) [0x000b6] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitBinary (System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b) [0x0016c] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x000d2] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitCombination (System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b, System.Action`1 combineWith) [0x00012] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitBinary (System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x000d2] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitMethodCall (System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression m) [0x0006a] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x000ec] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitMethodCall (System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression m) [0x000e6] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x000ec] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResults`1[T].CreateResultsHandle () [0x00037] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResults`1[T].get_ResultsHandle () [0x0000d] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at Realms.RealmResults`1[T].GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00073] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs:104 
06-06 17:46:15.337 I/MonoDroid(26505):   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:835
```

i suscpect DateTimeOffset could be causing the issue.

i checked the source code at https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet
but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you upgrade from Realm 0.74.1? There was a change in the date format, so maybe that is (part of) the problem.
Also, please note that the returned value from your method is going to be a `List` of `RealmObject` instances that will be invalid -- i.e. you will not be able to access the properties because the `Realm` is closed by the `using` statement.

Comment: Yes I upgraded from 0.74 to 0.75 today

Comment: i uninstall the Realm (and it dependencies and reinstall to 0.75), still not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. It happens when the class for `RealmObject`(in my case `Measurements`) is not inheriting directly from `RealmObject`.

My class `Measurements` was inheriting from a class `BaseModel` (i created this class for internal purpose) and this `BaseModel` class was inheriting from `RealmObject`.

When i removed this and made `Measurements` inherit directly from `RealmObject`, i doesn't throws exception.

From Dimitris Tavlikos 's comment,

**Realm Xamarin does not allow models to be further subclassed in any way. The CreateObject generic method only works if you use it for a class which descends directly from RealmObject.**

https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#model-inheritance

Comment: yes, this is part of their documentation: "Realm Xamarin does not allow models to be further subclassed in any way. The CreateObject generic method only works if you use it for a class which descends directly from RealmObject.". Here: https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#models

Comment: Apart from making this more flexible, in the short term we are improving the weaver detection of this situation to give you a better error message.